# get the output of byte [][] by using console.writeline in c# ,servicestack

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

![enter image description here][1]
    console.WriteLine( client.ZRangeByScore("myset", 0, 10, 0, 0).ToString());

`zrangebyscore` command is the type of `byte [][]`. Do we have a chance to convert it to string?
I g0t no error when i write it like that but,the output is

`System.Byte[][]`

while (reader.Read()) {

```
                client.Lists["name"].Append(reader["username"].ToString());
                client.Lists["name"].GetAll();
                client.Lists["followers"].Append(reader["reach"].ToString());
                client.Lists["followers"].GetAll();




                double [] array4=new double[client.LLen("followers")];
                for(int i=0;i<client.LLen("followers");i++){
                array4[i]=Convert.ToDouble(client.GetItemFromList("followers",i));

                }
                for(int i=0;i<client.LLen("name");i++){

                    client.AddItemToSortedSet("myset", client.GetItemFromList("name", i), array4[i]);


                }


                Console.WriteLine( client.ZRangeByScore("myset", 0, 10, 0, 0));
```

This is the some part of codes above.ZRangeByScore is a command that gives output of sorted set and its definition in servicestack is like that 'byte [][] RedisNativeClient.ZRangeByScore(string setID,long min , long max,int ? skip,int ? take)'
I can get the right output in redis client but also I want  to show it on Console Application

Comment: What format should ouput have? All values separated by comma?

Comment: What is `client.ZRangeByScore` method exactly?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", client.ZRangeByScore("myset", 0, 10, 0, 0).Cast<object>()));` What about that?

Comment: This depends entirely on the meaning of the return value. You'd have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

> I g0t no error when i write it like that but,the output is
>
> System.Byte[][]

This means you are calling .ToString() on a System.Byte[][].

The ToString() method does not have a generic implementation to show you all values of this multidimensional array, so you will have to do it on your own. You might want to iterate about the dimensions and put each dimension into its own line (table format) or whatever you choose as human-readable output of the console. This has to be done where you actually call the ToString() now.

Example:
you do this:

```
console.WriteLine( client.ZRangeByScore("myset", 0, 10, 0, 0).ToString());
```

you can change it to this:

```
var byteArray = client.ZRangeByScore("myset", 0, 10, 0, 0);

foreach(var array in byteArray)
{
  Console.WriteLine("this array has the size " + array.Length);
  foreach(var element in array)
  {
    Console.Write(element + "");
  }
}
```

[above code is not tested, just correct it if it fails to build]
You might want to wrap this into a function or override the ToString() in your class (you then might want to create a class for that..)

This is just one way how it can be done.

Comment: It does not matter to write ToString() actually , without the ToString() I'm getting same output,anyway I will try to write as table format

Comment: @reclusion The ToString() is automatically called as Console.WriteLine() expects Strings, Object.ToString()'s base Implementation is "return this.GetType()" i think. I will add an example of what you can do.

Comment: @reclusion glad to have helped. It would be nice if you accept the answer then, you will also get reputation for it.